# Only update uniform values in a fragment shader without redrawing everything - possible?

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm using OpenGL to draw a basic UI with knobs and buttons, which I'm trying to performance optimize as much as possible. The UI only needs to update on user input, but at the moment I'm updating it @ 60fps. Because of this, I want to keep the amount of OpenGL calls per frame to an absolute minimum.

The knobs are mapped as textures onto squares in an 2D orthogonal projection, via a fragment shader. The rotation of the knob is stored as a uniform float `rotation` in the shader.

Everything works just fine after I set the uniform value with `glUniform1f(…);` and call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, …);` but it seems wasteful to redraw the triangles every time since the position will be the same every time.

Ideally, I would just draw the geometry once, and only update the uniform values with `glUniform()` calls every time a value changed - but when I remove `glDrawArrays` from my render loop and update the uniform values before triggering a `glFlush()`, the fragment shaders stay the same.

Is this by design, and am I supposed to redraw the triangles to trigger a repaint of the fragment shader? Or is there a more performant workaround?

Comment: changing uniforms without rendering is possible you just do not render anything as without calling glDraw... no shaders are invoked so its pointless. What exactly you want to achieve by changing uniform? If your knobs are complicated geometry you can render them into texture once and then just render single textured quad instead... You can use also depth texture to preserve features (similar to bump mapping)

Comment: @Spektre I think I understand it now – fragment shaders will only get called when rendering something, then that means my question is impossible. I'll try to optimize in other ways then. Thank you